# Sum total time between two date columns for all records, grouped by other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure:

| id | user_id | action_type | action_start_time | action_end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4 | 2023-06-21 16:52:49.111 | 2023-06-21 16:55:49.022 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 2023-06-21 16:55:51.052 | 2023-06-21 17:10:19.100 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 | 2023-06-21 18:38:44.062 | 2023-06-21 18:59:51.025 |
| 4 | 16 | 1 | 2023-06-21 19:52:39.426 | 2023-06-21 20:01:49.127 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 2023-06-21 20:11:19.321 | 2023-06-21 21:55:49.132 |

And I need to calculate the total time each user spent per `action_type`.

I only managed to work with DATEDIFF to sum the number of seconds per row:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, action_start_time, action_end_time) AS TotalSeconds from my_table;
```

But I was not sure about how to group by each user id and action type.

Comment: Just `GROUP BY`: `select user_id, action_type, sum(datediff(...)) as total_seconds from mytable group by user_id, action_type`

Comment: @GMB thank you! `GROUP BY` was my first attempt but obviously I did not use it correctly. Using your syntax, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was not sure about how to group by each user id and action type

You simply do almost exactly what you say and *group by* those columns:

```
select user_id, action_type, 
  sum(DateDiff(second, action_start_time, action_end_time)) as TotalSeconds 
from my_table
group by user_id, action_type;
```